# Повторно запустить компонент(vue-countup-v2) на новом слайде

Tags: vue.js

Пишу на vue.js webpack
Есть код рабочий которые меняет слайды каждое N время. Был установлен vue-countup-v2 из npm.
Count up запускаться только на 1 слайде. Не получаться зацепится чтоб после смены слайда с новыми данные запустился и так по кругу надо.
Cсылка на [vue-countup-v2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-countup-v2)

В шаблон  из массива данных передаю в параметр endVal где метод должен заново отработать.

```js
import ICountUp from 'vue-countup-v2';  // Подключается компонент

export default {
  name: 'slideshow',
  data() {
  return {
    selectedIndex: 0,
    startVal: 0,
    decimals: 0,
    duration: 2.5,
    options: {
      useEasing: true,
      useGrouping: true,
      separator: ',',
      decimal: '.',
      prefix: '',
      suffix: ''
    },
    items: [
      {
        title: 'Center of osteopatia and rehabilitation',
        url_img: 'https://i.imgur.com/gQp3VSW.jpg',
        info_block: [
          {
            incremental: '800',
            description: 'Increasing the number of transactions from organic search results'
          },
          {
            incremental: '240',
            description: 'Raising your revenue'
          }

        ]
      },
      {
        title: 'SLide 2',
        url_img: 'https://newevolutiondesigns.com/images/freebies/space-wallpaper-5.jpg',
        info_block: [
          {
            incremental: '140',
            description: 'Increasing the numb organic search results'
          },
          {
            incremental: '790',
            description: 'Raising your revenue'
          }

        ]
      },
      {
        title: ' SLIDE 3',
        url_img: 'https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/4433836-space-wallpapers.jpg',
        info_block: [
          {
            incremental: '110',
            description: 'Increasing the number of trans'
          },
          {
            incremental: '99',
            description: 'Raising your revenue'
          }

        ]
      }
    ]
  }
},

methods: {
  select(index) {
    this.selectedIndex = index
  },
  index_dotnav: function (index) {
    this.selectedIndex = index
  },
  setMyTimeout(instance) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (++this.selectedIndex === this.items.length) {
      this.selectedIndex = 0;

    }

    this.setMyTimeout()
  }, 5000)
},
onReady(instance) {
  instance.update(this.endVal + 100);
}
},
mounted() {
  this.setMyTimeout();
},
components: {
  'app-count-up': ICountUp
}


};
```

```css
    ul {
        padding-left: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .img-block,
    section > *,
    .uk-slideshow,
    .uk-slideshow > ul {
        height: 100vh !important;
    }

    .information-slide .uk-container {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin: auto 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .slideshow > div.dotnav-block {
        top: 50%;
        left: 95%;

        z-index: 2;
    }

    .slideshow > div.dotnav-block li a {
        background: #fff;
    }

    .slideshow > div.dotnav-block li.active a {
        width: 13px;
        height: 13px;
    }

    .slideshow > div.dotnav-block ul {
        align-items: center;
    }

    .slideshow .slideshow-items > li {
        display: none;
    }

    .slideshow .slideshow-items > li.active {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
    }

    .slideshow .slideshow-items > li img {
        height: 100%;
        width: auto;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Тест</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.14/css/uikit.min.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="app">
    <section>
    <div class="uk-child-width-1-2" uk-grid>
<div>
<h1>{{ message }}</h1>
</div>
<div>
<div class="slideshow">

    <ul class="slideshow-items">

    <li v-for="(item,index) in items"  :class="{'active':index===0}" v-on:click="select($event)">

    <div class="information-slide">
    <div class="img-block">
    <img v-bind:src="item.url_img" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="uk-container">
    <div class="title title-1">{{item.title}}</div>
<div class="info-block">
    <div class="info" v-for="(iblock,ind) in item.info_block">
    <div class="incremental"><span>+</span>
    <app-count-up
:startVal="startVal"
:endVal="iblock.incremental"
:decimals="decimals"
:duration="duration"
:options="options"
@ready="onReady"></app-count-up>
    <span>%</span>
    </div>
    <div class="description descr-1">{{iblock.description}}</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>

<div class="dotnav-block uk-position-bottom-center uk-position-small">
    <ul class="uk-dotnav uk-dotnav-vertical">
    <li :class="{'active':index===0}"   v-for="(item,index) in items" v-on:click="index_dotnav(index)">
    <a href="#">Item {{index}}</a></li>

</ul>
</div>

</div>

</div>

</div>
</section>
</div>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.14/js/uikit.min.js"></script>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Прежде чем снова запускать, нужно сначала завершить, разве не логично?

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать по хитрому: при смене слайда на короткое время его скрывать с помощью `v-if`, а после показывать заново.

Т.е. этот компонент перезагрузится и сработает заново.

Для этого советую использовать $nextTick.

Comment: Согласно Мартину- в программировании нет слова "хитрый", если вы говорите "хитрый код", это на самом деле значит что код сложный, и его стоит переписать на более простой.